# Only one command line argument with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to implement an command line argument with argparse in a way that only none or once is accepted. Multiple occurences should be rejected.

I use the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
cmd_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
cmd_parser.add_argument('-o', dest='outfile')
cmd_line = cmd_parser.parse_args()
print(cmd_line.outfile)
```

One argument gives the expected result:

```
./test.py -o file1
file1
```

When issuing the argument twice, the first occurence is silently ignored:

```
./test.py -o file1 -o file2
file2
```

I also tried `nargs=1` and `action='store'` without reaching the desired result.

How can I tell argparse to reject multiple argument occurances?

Comment: A more recent answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68170827/how-do-i-tell-argparse-to-allow-an-argument-only-once, suggests using the 'append' action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [argparse - disable same argument occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032514/argparse-disable-same-argument-occurrences)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be arranged with a custom Action:

```
import argparse

class Once(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Once, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._count = 0

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        # print('{n} {v} {o}'.format(n=namespace, v=values, o=option_string))
        if self._count != 0:
            msg = '{o} can only be specified once'.format(o=option_string)
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(None, msg)
        self._count = 1
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)

cmd_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
cmd_parser.add_argument('-o', dest='outfile', action=Once, default='/tmp/out')
cmd_line = cmd_parser.parse_args()
print(cmd_line.outfile)
```

---

You can specify a default:

```
% script.py 
/tmp/out
```

You can specify `-o` once:

```
% script.py -o file1 
file1
```

But specifying `-o` twice raises an error:

```
% script.py -o file1 -o file2
usage: script.py [-h] [-o OUTFILE]
script.py: error: -o can only be specified once
```

Comment: Thank you - works as expected. I was looking for a solution within argparse, thats why I did overlooked the custom Action approach.

Comment: I would add to the check the default value, `if getattr(namespace, self.dest) is not None and self.default is None:` because if you specify a default value it would fail, and not because the argument is repeated.

Comment: @lasote: I think using that condition would allow `-o` to be specified more than once without raising an error since `self.default` will not be `None` if you specify a non-None default value. I've changed the code above to accommodate a default value in a different way above.